# Why does this GStreamer pipeline work with filesink but not with ximagesink/autovideosink?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

On my Ubuntu system, I can run this pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink`

And view the test pattern at 30fps.

I can also launch this pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v rtspsrc 'location=...' ! decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4`

...and can use gst-play-1.0 to view the test.mp4 file without a problem.

But these two pipelines don't open a view window, but also give no errors with DEBUG turned up all the way:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v rtspsrc 'location=...' ! decodebin ! ximagesink`

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v rtspsrc 'location=...' ! decodebin ! autovideosink`

Works fine on my mac, but no window on Ubuntu.

Weirder: even with -v, there is no output of the pad negotiation for autovideosink. Also nothing at all  with GST_DEBUG=autovideosink:6 ... ?!?

I've never seen gstreamer go silent.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like two issues to me. Why there is no output is unclear to me. Perhaps a typo?

As for the pipelines, you most likely want to use `videoconvert` or `autovideoconvert` before your video sink. If your graphics driver doesn't support the color space output by the decoder it needs to convert it to a format that satisfies the sink.

Answer (score 0):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v rtspsrc 'location=...' ! decodebin ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4 -e
```

Adding "-e" parameter to gst-launch-1.0 should do the job for you
This parameter basically write an EOS(End of stream) header to the mp4file before closing it, this i

Answer (score 0):

you can use the GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR env to dump the dot file of pipeline. reference to [Getting pipeline graphs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html?gi-language=c#getting-pipeline-graphs)

then you can see which decoder(nvidia/vaapi/software) the decodebin use, and see which sink is used. and they whould be matched.

if the decoder and the sink do not match, then you can use nvvideoconvert/vaapipostproc copy the frame buffer to host memory and use ximagesink to do the render. or you can choose correct decoder and sink